# Xcode 5 not printing exception detail

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I have a project built for iOS 7 and it worked fine so far, but after a Git merge, some settings or something became corrupted and **exceptions are not outputted to console** anymore. So the "Terminating app due to uncaught exception" error message is never displayed in console. I've tried the project on both the device and the simulator, same thing. I cannot find the reason why is this and how to fix it and I am humbly asking for your help.

**The facts:**

- debugger is working and running,
- debugger stops and highlights correct line,
- all exceptions breakpoint is active,
- NSLog commands are working,
- po command in lldb is working.

**What I have tried before asking for help?**

- Cleaning (including build folder) and rebuilding project,
- Restarting Xcode,
- Restarting OS X,
- Reconnecting device,
- Rebooting device.

What else can I do? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried diffing the git commits to find out what was changed?

Comment: Do you press the continue button after the debugger stops?  In my experience the details are not printed until you press the continue button twice after the debugger stops at an exception breakpoint.

Comment: I've checked the commit, nothing was changed in project files. Only source code files. @borrrden, of course I tried that. Doesn't change a thing, even when debugging is stopped, nothing is outputted to console regarding exceptions.

Comment: "even when debugging is stopped" -> If you stop the debugger, of course nothing will get printed.  I assume that was just bad wording?

Comment: @borrrden What I meant was, that I keep clicking continue until it halts on UIApplicationMain in main.h and then the debugging is stopped. Even at that point was no exception information is displayed.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. It's driving me absolutely nuts. Same issues as OP, on both simulator and device. I've also made sure that "Log Exceptions" is turned on in the scheme.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue when trying to debug an autolayout crash. Not sure if this applies to all cases, but here's my solution:

I did some hunting, and came across this link:

[Investigating NSExceptions with LLDB](http://humblebeesoft.com/blog/?p=36)

That led me to mess around with exception breakpoints to try to figure out what the issue was. In my case, I could always find the description on `$eax`, so I decided to add an action to the breakpoint, so I don't have to debug it each time. This caused it to always print `$eax` without a breakpoint, so it pretty much acts like I want it to (print the exception description, continue crashing).

Steps:

[image: Add an Exception Breakpoint]

[image: Edit the breakpoint you just added]

[image: Add an action to <code>po $eax</code>, and check "automatically continue after evaluating"]

Solved the issue I was currently having, and I'm sure variations on this solution (`po $ebx`, `po [NSThread callStackSymbols]`, etc) should get around most issues with missing exception descriptions.

Comment: I will add a tricky point here that will help out also. ctrl click and then go to "Move Breakpoint to" and then "User". It will make user specific.